# Implementing odbc wrapper for Sql server. Reading database data as characters or asking driver to convert the data to C type

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, odbc

I have written a database wrapper using odbc to communicate with sql server database.
It is working but how i am doing is I am reading all the data types as characters(number of characters specified while binding the column using SQLBindCol) and changing the returned characters to the required datatype in my application.

I know this method is not very efficient as i am converting the returned characters every time to the required datatype in my application, i can imagine this would take an extra time for conversion.

I see the microsoft reference for SQLBindCol stating

> When it is retrieving data from the data source with SQLFetch, SQLFetchScroll, SQLBulkOperations, or SQLSetPos, the driver converts the data to this type

which is what i need and i think which will be efficient compared to my code (reading everything as characters.)

[sqlbindcol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindcol-function?view=sql-server-2017) [sqlfetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlfetch-function?view=sql-server-2017)

Below is the order of ODBC API Function calls

- SQLAllocHandle (to allocate environment handle)
- SQLSetEnvAttr
- SQLAllocHandle (to allocate database handle)
- SQLDriverConnect
- SQLAllocHandle (to allocate statement handle)
- SQLExecDirect
- SQLBindCol
- SQLFetch.

Every time when I bind the column, I am specifying, TargetType as sql_char and the number of characters to be pushed to the application buffer (*void) when sqlfetch is called.

When I want to read the data which is a big string (for example xml data) and of unknown size, this method is not workable.

I want to know if I read the all the datatypes as characters like how i did? How to read all the data in the returned result column without specifying the number characters to be pushed into buffer?

I read from the documents we can ask the driver to do the conversion to the specified C type in SQLBindCol. How to achieve this? 
My structure to store the column information is

```
struct ColValInfo
{
    ColValInfo(): pValue(0){}

    SQLPOINTER pValue; // typedef void * SQLPOINTER;
    SQLINTEGER StrLen_or_Ind; // typedef long  SQLINTEGER;
};
```

pValue is a void pointer. if driver want to do the conversion and return the data to pValue. what all the necessary things to be done.

Comment: Why are you writing a wrapper?  Have you considered something like [Dapper object wrapper for SQL Server](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)?

Comment: I wanted to write my own wrapper library in c++.

Comment: for fun?  Seriously, though, why re-write something that has already been written by some of the most accomplished coders in the world?  Spend your time working on something that hasn't already been written.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. I should have considered Dapper object wrapper, but I thought writing a thin wrapper would be very simple, that myself can do it. Now i have spent quite some time and finished, Only that i have to change  the way i read the data. I want to know which is better method? Read everything as characters or ask driver to convert the data to required datatype? Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a call to [`SQLDescribeCol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribecol-function?view=sql-server-2017) before `SQLBindCol` call.

It will both give you the column type and the column size.
You will then allocate your buffers accordingly using a C type corresponding to the SQL type of the column and will not convert any data.